# How to hide my xmpp stanzas in browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am working on a web based application. web client communicates with openfire using xmpp. For this i am using strophe javascript library.It is working perfectly fine. Right now any user visiting my website can watch exactly what stanza was sent for some action using chrome's network console. I want to hide the stanzas. How can i do this?

Comment: You can't, it's network traffic. The client only sees their own traffic.

Comment: isnt some encryption strategy possible?

Comment: Why? Again, the user's can see their own chat, so what's there to hide?

Comment: well we not just doing chat in this application. There are alot of things we are doing through custom openfire plugins and custom stanzas.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do not want the user to see should done server side. Anything that is sent over the wire through post/get can be seen by the client. Encryption would only slow down someone who really wants to see what it is, not to mention the overhead on your script doing the encryption.